# Disallow PHP code overriding php.ini error_reporting

Tags: php, fpm

Can i disallow PHP override `php.ini` error_reporting settings? And take this settings only from `php.ini`.

```
php.init file have: error_reporting = E_ERROR|E_PARSE

PHP code have: error_reporting(E_WARNING|E_PARSE);
```

But this PHP line is in project core and i can't edit it and I don't need `E_WARNING`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i disallow PHP override php.ini error_reporting settings?

You can disallow use of `error_reporting()` function in your code with use of [disable_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) configuration directive. The downside is that you cannot have

```
disable_functions = error_reporting
```

set per vhost (i.e. via `php_admin_value`) but it must be set in main `php.ini` which may be problematic in some configurations.

Also I believe that your question exposed different problem and you are not fixing it here, but rather working around.

Answer (score 0):

edit: just occured to me, you can use php runkit to do this instead of messing with the source code,

option 1: 
install runkit ( https://github.com/zenovich/runkit / https://github.com/runkit7/runkit7 ), add `runkit.internal_override=1` in php.ini, and run

```
runkit_function_rename("error_reporting","original_error_reporting");
runkit_function_add("error_reporting",function(int $ignored = NULL){return original_error_reporting();});
```

before running your intended code (you can also add this code in a file pointed to by the `auto_prepend_file` php.ini option to make sure it runs before any other code)

- or option 2: edit the php interpreter source code,

in php-src/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c find

```
/* {{{ proto int error_reporting([int new_error_level])
   Return the current error_reporting level, and if an argument was passed - change to the new level */
ZEND_FUNCTION(error_reporting)
```

then right below that find

```
if (ZEND_NUM_ARGS() != 0) {
```

replace it with

```
if (0) {
```

then recompile PHP, and voila, error_reporting arguments are ignored :)

in git revision ab8094c666048b747481df0b9da94e08cadc4160 , which is 7.3.0-dev (slightly after 7.3.0-beta1), it is on line 736, see https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ab8094c666048b747481df0b9da94e08cadc4160/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#L736

Comment: This is really bad practice though! Every time you update PHP you need to think about this modification.

Comment: @SketchyCoder well, it just occurred to me that you can use runkit instead of messing with the source code ... but still probably not a good idea ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Both true! ;-) Question is why would you ever want this, this smells like bad design.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. While it is not the cleanest approach possible, I personally see a value in such approach is **specific cases**. So it is good for people to know that that they can go alternate way, Therefore I believe you do not deserve any downvote for goind that way as your answer definitely adds the value here and alternatives are always good things to have.